# Task-execution-ETA in AppEngine Push Queues given lack of server clock synchronization

Tags: google-app-engine, countdown, task-queue, clock-synchronization

[AppEngine Push Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) allow Tasks to be scheduled for future execution if they are added with the [`TaskOptions.etaMillis(...)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#etaMillis%28long%29) option. This method expects a `long` parameter that specifies the time when to execute the task in absolute ms, just as returned by [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

Given that AppEngine makes no guarantees about server clock synchronization and the clocks can be off by something on the order of HOURS!!! (see ["Google I/O 2010 - Data pipelines with Google App Engine" at 0:36:07](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSDC_TU7rtc&t=36m7s)), how can this be reliable?

Let's consider the following example:

- An http request comes in and gets routed to an instance whose clock happens to be 30 mins ahead
- During the request handling, I would like to defer some batch processing to a background task
- I would like to have the results available to report back to the user within around 10s
- So, I schedule the task with an ETA of `System.currentTimeMillis() + 10,000`
- Given the 30 minute clock skew, this ETA actually corresponds to 30 mins and 10 secs from now
- Thus, if the task is now processed by a different instance, it might be on hold for over 30 mins
- Needless to say, for the user it would seem as if my service had died

Is this prevented somehow in the underlying API? If not, how can Task ETAs be useful at all? Wouldn't the ETA have to be specified as a relative time rather than an absolute one for this to work?

The really sad part is that there actually is a function called [`TaskOptions.countdownMillis(...)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis%28long%29) that does expect a relative time, but looking at the 
[source code that ultimately handles this value](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueImpl.java#579), one sees that it is simply converted to an absolute time specification based off the same highly unreliable `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Worse still: If you don't specify an ETA or a countdown, this function simply uses the current system time rather than 0, so even a task that you expect to execute immediately might end up being on hold for an hour or more!

Is this some major bug or am I missing something?

Also, the same should apply to leases of Tasks in [Pull Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the countdown to 10,000 ms then the task will usually run in about 10 seconds, but sometimes the task can be delayed by a few minutes. They are intended for tasks that the end user isn't waiting for.

Relative times would work if all processing was handled by a single server with perfect availability. Instead we have many servers, each with imperfect availability, so we add tasks with absolute time, knowing that clock skew is usually small.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, my concern is correct and there might indeed be an occasional case where task execution is delayed significantly, but (a) this should only happen rarely because overall the clock synchronization isn't too bad and (b) task queues were never meant to provide an ETA guarantee anyways and should therefore not be used for anything time critical?